# useState set method not changing the value - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to send user to backend in function `handleJoin()`.
After setUser is called, the initial data not changed.

How to fix it without using `class`

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Join from "./components/Join";

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ });

  // Send user data to backend
  const handleJoin = (input) => {     
    console.log(input);               // >   {name: "myname"}

    setUser(input);                   //     Not working!

    console.log(user);                // >   { }

    // I want to connect backend here
    // But the user objet is empty
  };

  return <Join onJoin={handleJoin} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: How can we answer this without seeing what the `Join` component does, and in particular how its `onJoin` prop is used?

Answer (score 4):

`user` will be updated on the next render after calling `setUser`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Join from "./components/Join";

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  // This is a side effect that will occur when `user`
  // changes (and on initial render). The effect depends
  // `user` and will run every time `user` changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      // Connect to backend here
    }
  }, [user])

  // Send user data to backend
  const handleJoin = (input) => {     
    console.log(input);
    setUser(input);
  };

  return <Join onJoin={handleJoin} />;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

State update is not synchronous so it will not update user object right away but it will be updated asynchronously. So Either you can use `input` which is going to be user value to be sent to backend or you can use `useEffect()` hook which will be triggered when `user` value will be udpated

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // this will be triggered whenever user will be updated
  console.log('updated user', user);
  if (user) {
    // connect to backend now
  }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: `user` will initially be truthy since its initial value is `{}`.

Comment: it conveys the idea

Comment: When I try this, the code inside the useEffect runs endlessly.

Comment: There must be updating/setting user value inside that useEffect which is causing cyclic rerender since useEffect has `user` dependency and it will run whenever user will change